# Application launch at startup (Login) in mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-elcapitan

How to make MAC application which will launch at starting of MAC or Login.
How can we add into login items in ElCapitian.

Comment: Posible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625255/how-can-i-make-program-automatically-startup-on-login)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30032586/2836621

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make program automatically startup on login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625255/how-can-i-make-program-automatically-startup-on-login)

Answer (score 1):

A Launch Daemon is a single process that runs in the background for all users. In contrast a Launch Agent is an application that launches when a user logs-in. Apple's documentation clearly describes these along with how to [Create Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)